# Memoization with recursion

Tags: haskell

I am trying to understand [Haskell realization of memoization](http://www.haskell.org/haskellwiki/Memoization) , but I don't get how it works:

```
memoized_fib :: Int -> Integer
memoized_fib = (map fib [0..] !!)
    where fib 0 = 0
              fib 1 = 1
              fib n = memoized_fib(n - 2) + memoized_fib(n - 1)
```

First of all I even don't understand why 'map'-function get three parameters (function - fib, list [0..], and ||), but not two how it must do.

**Updated:**

I have tried to rewrite the code, but get the different result:

```
f' :: (Int -> Int) -> Int -> Int
f' mf 0 = 0
f' mf 1 = 1
f' mf n = mf(n - 2) + mf(n - 1)

f'_list :: [Int]
f'_list = map (f' faster_f') [0..]

faster_f' :: Int -> Int
faster_f' n = f'_list !! n
```

Why? Is the any error in my reasoning?

Comment: they could've put some extra parenthesis there to make it a bit more obvious `(map fib [0..] !!)` == `((map fib [0..]) !!)`

Comment: The different result in your update is because of `Int` overflow. Use `Integer` instead; apart from that it seems right to me at first glance.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

First: Haskell supports operator sections. So `(+ 2)` is equal to `\ x -> x + 2`. This means the expression with `map` is equal to `\ x -> map fib [0..] !! x`.

Secondly, how this works: this is taking advantage of Haskell's [call-by-need](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Evaluation_strategy#Call_by_need) evaluation strategy (its laziness).

Initially, the list which results from the `map` is not evaluated. Then, when you need to get to some particular index, all the elements up to that point get evaluated. However, once an element is evaluated, it does not get evaluated again (as long as you're referring to the same element). This is what gives you memoization.

Basically, Haskell's lazy evaluation strategy involves memoizing forced values. This memoized `fib` function just relies on that behavior.

Here "forcing" a value means evaluating a deferred expression called a thunk. So the list is basically initially stored as a "promise" of a list, and forcing it turns that "promise" into an actual value, and a "promise" for more values. The "promises" are just thunks, but I hope calling it a promise makes more sense.

I'm simplifying a bit, but this should clarify how the actual memoization works.

Comment: Thank. I have tried to rewrite my code with new knowledge, but get the different result (updated section in my question). Why? As I see this pieces of code must be equal.

Comment: Why, for instance, in function calls `memoized_fib(n - 2)` and  `memoized_fib(n - 1)`, the list `map fib [0..]` refer to the same list in memory?

Comment: The expression with map is critically **not** equal to `\x -> map fib [0..] !! x`. That would destroy the sharing! (Unless you compile with GHC's optimizations which is smart enough to restore the sharing.) Instead, it is equal to `(!!) (map fib [0..])`.

Comment: (Or if you do want to show a fully applied version, I'd suggest `let fibs = map fib [0..] in \x -> fibs !! x`.)

Answer (score 2):

`map` does not take three parameters here.

```
(map fib [0..] !!)
```

partially applies (slices) the function `(!!)` with `map fib [0..]`, a list, as its first (left-hand) argument.

Answer (score 2):

Maybe it's clearer written it as:

```
memoized_fib n = (map fib [0..]) !! n
```

so it's just taking the `n`th element from the list, and the list is evaluated lazily.

This [operator section](http://www.haskell.org/haskellwiki/Section_of_an_infix_operator) stuff is exactly the same as normal partial application, but for infix operators. In fact, if we write the same form with a regular function instead of the `!!` infix operator, see how it looks:

```
import Data.List (genericIndex)

memoized_fib :: Int -> Integer
memoized_fib = genericIndex (map fib [0..])
    where fib 0 = 0
              fib 1 = 1
              fib n = memoized_fib(n - 2) + memoized_fib(n - 1)
```

Comment: Here is two version of function (http://pastebin.com/sA6ib2kp). Why the first one run faster, but second one - slower?

Comment: Because the list is shared in the first version but not the second version.